# Can someone explain what this chown is actually doing?

Tags: chown

Can someone in detail explain what exactly the following command that a tutorial has instructed me to issue is doing?

```
chown -R $USER:$GROUP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown

So it's recursively setting owner and group for any subsequently specified directory, and all below it.

```
chown [OPTION]... [OWNER][:[GROUP]] FILE..

-R, --recursive
    operate on files and directories recursively
```

Comment: There seems to be more to the $USER:$GROUP then variables. This was from a paid video tutorial on setting up a database and was done during the installation phase. It created a directory for its data files and then the next step was to issue that command exactly as typed (except the path for the directory /var/log/data followed).

Comment: OK.  If you're unsure, do a `echo user=$USER group=$GROUP` prior to running the `chown`.  That will definitively report to you the values that the variables currently have.

Answer (score 0):

chown basically means changing the ownership of filesystem object(s) like files,directories and links etc.

```
chown -R $USER:$GROUP file1 dir1 ...
```

here we are doing two things

1. changing the ownership of `file1` and `dir1` to `$USER` simultaneously
2. changing the group of `file1 dir1` to `$GROUP`